# Change simple inline modal window css script

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the 'simple inline modal window css' script from sohtanaka.com. Since this website is offline I can not find my answer now.

Can someone help me out?

I want to show the popup only once when the page is loaded, no it keeps showing.

Div that contains popup:

```
<div id="popup_load" class="popup_block">
<b>Lorem ipsum dolores sit amet</b>
</div>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.fn.popOpen = function(){

        var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
        var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

        //Pull Query & Variables from href URL
        var query= popURL.split('?');
        var dim= query[1].split('&');
        var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value


        //Fade in the Popup and add close button
        $('#' + popID).fadeIn('slow').css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="images/close.png" class="btn_close" title="<?php echo $lang['sluit'] ?>" /></a>');

        //Define margin for center alignment (vertical   horizontal) - we add 80px to the height/width to accomodate for the padding  and border width defined in the css
        var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 20) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 20) / 2;

        //Apply Margin to Popup
        $('#' + popID).css({
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        //Fade in Background
        $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
        $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) is used to fix the IE Bug on fading transparencies
    };

    $('a.poplight[href=#?w=400]').popOpen(); //Run popOpen function once on load

    //Close Popups and Fade Layer
    //$('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
    $('a.close').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close...
        $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
            $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //fade them both out
            location.reload(); // reload page
        });
        return false;
    });

    popOpen
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is that a typo?  popOpen on the last line before </script> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your clicking on an actual link to close the popup, wich probably contains a # sign as href, wich causes the browser to reload the page. Try something like this for you close function

```
$('a.close').live('click', function(e) { //When clicking on the close...
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
            $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //fade them both out
            location.reload(); // reload page
        });
        return false;
    });
```

This prevents the link from doing its default action and should cause the popup to show up just once on loading

Answer (score 0):

set a cookie when you first show your popup. Then before you show it again, check if the cookie is present before showing it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (cookie is set){
        return ;
    }

    show cookie code

    then mark cookie as set
});
```